# node-canvas & TypeScript: Assertion failed: (tmp.table_size - hash_table_sizes < ARRAY_LENGTH (hash_table_sizes))

Tags: node.js, typescript, canvas, cairo, node-canvas

I am using node-canvas for drawing an image, this error occurs when the code is ran:

```
Assertion failed: (tmp.table_size - hash_table_sizes < ARRAY_LENGTH (hash_table_sizes)), function _cairo_hash_table_manage, file cairo-hash.c, line 286.
/var/folders/ll/02j8nvys66176tszvw01w1c00000gq/T/start6586898863.sh: line 2: 17744 Abort trap: 6           ts-node src/index.ts
```

Please notice that **I use TypeScript**, and this fact *may* be the reason of the error. I also found [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1357) opened & fixed on GitHub. As it was marked as fixed and worked for other users, I can think that TypeScript code compiling causes this error.

Code:

```
const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(1772, 633);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Register fonts
    Canvas.registerFont(join(__dirname, `../Fonts/Panton-BlackCaps.otf`), {
      family: 'Panton-BlackCaps',
    });
    Canvas.registerFont(join(__dirname, `../Fonts/coolvetica rg.otf`), {
      family: 'Coolvetica',
    });

    // Get the background image and draw it
    const background = await Canvas.loadImage(
      join(__dirname, `../Images/background.png`)
    );
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Get info about the user
    const username = `${member.user.username}#${member.user.discriminator}`;
    const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(
      member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' })
    );

    // Draw the avatar
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(322, 280, 208, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Position of the avatar
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.shadowColor = '#000000';
    ctx.shadowBlur = 16;
    ctx.clip();

    ctx.drawImage(avatar, 322, 280, 500, 500);

    // Checks username length and draws text depending on it
    if (username.length >= 14) {
      ctx.font = '70 px Coolvetica';
      ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
      ctx.shadowColor = '#000000';
      ctx.shadowBlur = 7;
      ctx.fillText(username, 322.42, 546.79);
    } else {
      ctx.font = '93 px Coolvetica';
      ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
      ctx.shadowColor = '#000000';
      ctx.shadowBlur = 7;
      ctx.fillText(username, 322.42, 546.79);
    }

    // Draws the WELCOME! text
    ctx.font = '195.35 px Panton-BlackCaps';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.shadowColor = '#000000';
    ctx.shadowBlur = 7;
    ctx.fillText('WELCOME!', 1177, 287.55);

    // Draws the Enjoy your stay! text
    ctx.font = '99.71 px Coolvetica';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.shadowColor = '#000000';
    ctx.shadowBlur = 7;
    ctx.fillText('Enjoy your stay!', 1177, 398.46);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `npm rebuild` fully resolves this issue.

Deleting `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` will also work as an alternative method.